# How to whiten data without computing covariance matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

I have a batch of 128 images.  Each image is 320x320.  I would like to whiten this group of images so i form a matrix $X$ which is 102400 x 128.  102400 dimensions and 128 observations.

To whiten X requires the outer product $XX^T$ which results in a 102400 x 102400 matrix which consumes too much memory.  Is there another way to whiten this matrix without computing this large outer product?